# tf.print has no result

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to use `tf.print` to show tensor value, but it has no result?

This is my code and is there something wrong for that:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()  
a = tf.constant([1.0, 3.0])
tf.print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation of `tf.Print`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Print) - that's deprecated and suggests to use `tf.print`:

Note that tf.print returns a no-output operator that directly prints the output. **Outside of defuns or eager mode, this operator will not be executed unless it is directly specified in `session.run` or used as a control dependency for other operators.**

This is only a concern in graph mode. Below is an example of how to ensure `tf.print` executes in graph mode:

```
sess = tf.Session()
with sess.as_default():
    tensor = tf.range(10)
    print_op = tf.print(tensor)
    with tf.control_dependencies([print_op]):
      out = tf.add(tensor, tensor)
    sess.run(out)
```

Hence, if you enable the eager mode your code will work as you expected, if you want to continue using the static-graph mode you have to use `sess.run`

Comment: Why are you talking about `tf.Print`? The OP never mentions it. It only mentions `tf.print`.

Comment: Because only in the docs of tf.Print, at that time, there was a reference about tf.print

Answer (score 0):

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant([1.0, 3.0])

init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    print(sess.run(a))
```

is what I'd do. Import tensorflow, set up your variables, set up and run the initializer for them, and then print the session evaluating the constant

Comment: I do not want to use `sess.run`, I want to know why no output for `tf.print`.